# How to increment the number of INSERT IGNORE into a UNIQUE column?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates, unique

I have a simple table of list of words, as the word column is `UNIQUE`. Thus, I `INSERT` words with

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO words (word) VALUES ('word1'), ('word2'), ...
```

I want to add a new column "number of occurrence" to count the number of `INSERT`s (which was `IGNORE`d). When `INSERT` ignores if the word exists, I want to increment the value (+1) of "number of occurrence".

**EDIT:** I am looking for a general method; e.g. for using word_map as

```
INSER IGNORE INTO word_map (word_id, post_id) 
VALUES ('word_id1', 'post_id1'), ('word_id2', 'post_id2')...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO words
  (myword, cnt)
VALUES ('example', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    cnt = cnt + 1;
```

See docs on [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: but this method does not work on INSERT of multiple values as `INSERT IGNORE INTO words (word) VALUES ('key1'),('key2), ...`

Comment: @Ali, could you show the insert statement that failed and the text of the error?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake. It works perfectly! Thanks again and apology for bothering!